# Перемещение объекта по координатам в цикле

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте!

Есть робот, который перемещается из **(x, y)** в **(x2, y2)**

Т.е. после каждого его шага точка на поле должна перемещаться (`f()` должна рисовать перемещение робота на поле).

Алгоритм перемещения робота написал, но как реализовать анимацию на ***javafx***? Может кто-нибудь набросать примерный код для `f()`.

```
 while (( robot.getX()!= toX) | ( robot.getY()!= toY)) {
        robot.stepForward();
        f(robot.getX, robot.getY); 
    }
```

Comment: Я не очень понял, что вам дать?

Comment: Мне кажется, вопрос должен был быть "Как отрисовать поле с роботом из двумерного массива"